# How to check with WINAPI file path is disk or file or directory?

Tags: winapi

How to check with WINAPI file  path is disk or file or directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [GetFileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364944(v=VS.85).aspx).

**Edit:** You can also check [SHGetFileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762179(v=VS.85).aspx)

Comment: But how to check is file path a disk?

Comment: Simply, a disk is a path that ends with a colon

Comment: I think it is possible to check by WINAPI

Answer (score 4):

Could try FindFirstFile:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Once you have the find data (passed as the 2nd argument to that function):

```
if(result->dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
{
    //file is a directory
}
else
{
    //file is not a directory
}
```

Also, to see if something is a volume, could try something like:

```
if(result->dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT)
{
    if(result->dwReserved0 == IO_REPARSE_TAG_MOUNT_POINT)
    {
        //path is a volume; try using GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint for info
    }
}
```

HTH

Comment: Something else that may be useful: http://api.farmanager.com/en/winapi/win32_find_data.html  [explanation of WIN32_FIND_DATA structure].

Comment: But how to check is file path a disk?

Comment: See if the path has a drive letter in front of it? All UNC's take the form "\\server\share\file_path" No drive letter.

Answer (score 1):

See if the path has a drive letter in front of it? All UNC's take the form "\\server\share\file_path" No drive letter.

Out of curiousity I looked this up. Based on this MSDN article [**Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), it seems my advice is exactly how it says it should be done.

Comment: Note that drive letters are sometimes permitted before UNC paths: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/11/22/495740.aspx